# Cleanest way to include urls in Moodle emails

Tags: php, email, moodle

I'd like to know which is the cleanest way to insert an url in an email sent by Moodle module.

So far I'm using this formula, what IMHO I don't think is the cleanest way:

```
$url = $CFG->wwwroot.'/mod/<mymodulename>/view.php?id='.$cm->id;
```

The things I don't like here are:

- Using $CFG->wwwroot
- /mod/<mymodulename> needs to be provided always. (Assume here that I'm using a constant instead of a hardcoded string).

I expected Moodle to have a function to provide this out of the box just when providing module script. I've tried moodle_url but this function doesn't provide the path to the php script when used this way:

```
new moodle_url('view.php?id='.$cm->id);
```

I just get:

```
view.php?id=XX
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `new moodle_url('/view.php?id='.$cm->id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
$url = new moodle_url('/mod/<mymodulename>/view.php', array('id' => $cm->id));
echo html_writer::link($url, get_string('linktitle', 'mod_mymodulename'));
```

Comment: This approach is pretty clean. In an ideal world I'd expect to not provide the module path to Moodle. Thanks!

Comment: Oh you can if you have the module by using

    html_writer::link($cm->get_url(), format_string($cm->name, true));

Answer (score 0):

You can use following statement:

This is Absolute path of file

> $url = new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/mod//view.php', array('id' => $cm->id));